# How to mock a service with FakeItEasy?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I have a simple entity framework repository that is accessed via a service call (please refer to
[this UML diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU64X.png) to see the relevant classes). I am trying to test the service as follows

```
public class ProductServiceTests
{
    private IProductService sut;
    private IProductRepository productRepo;
    [Fact]
    public async Task CanCallGetProductById()
    {
        //Arrange
        productRepo = new Fake<IProductRepository>().FakedObject;
        sut = new ProductService(productRepo);
        var id = 1;
        var expectation = new Product { Id = id };
        A.CallTo(() => sut.GetProductById(id)).Returns(expectation);

        // Act
        var result = await sut.GetProductById(id);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(id, result.Id);
    }
}
```

However, this leads to the following exception`System.ArgumentException : Object 'ProductService' of type ProductService is not recognized as a fake object.`

Which implies that I probably need to use a mock of the service as follows

```
 sut = new Fake<IProductService>().FakedObject;
```

This approach, however, is also problematic: the call to the function `await sut.GetProductById(id)` does not actually invoke any code under test. Indeed, if I throw an exception, the test still passes

```
    public async Task<Product> GetProductById(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        //return await _productRepository.GetAll().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

**Edit**
After some troubleshooting, I realized that, indeed, the code I am trying to test is not actually reached. For example, the following test

`A.CallTo(() => productRepo.GetAll()).MustHaveHappened();`

fails with a message that `Product.GetAll() Expected to find it once or more but no calls were made to the fake object.`

Can please someone explains how I should fix this error?

**Edits**

The `IProductRepository` and `IProductService` are defined as follows:

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    IQueryable<Product> GetAll();
}
public interface IProductService
{
    Task<Product> GetProductById(int id);
}
```

And the `ProductService` is implemented as follows

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;

    public ProductService(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }
   

    public async Task<Product> GetProductById(int id)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return await _productRepository.GetAll()
                                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The general approach when using fakes (or mocks or whatever) to help test a service is to mock the system under test's collaborators (in this case, `IProductService`), and to use a *real* system under test (if you don't use a real system under test, your system isn't "under test"). So, taking your original code and adapting, you'd want something like this:

```
public class ProductServiceTests
{
    private IProductService sut;
    private IProductRepository productRepo;
    [Fact]
    public async Task CanCallGetProductById()
    {
        //Arrange
        productRepo = new Fake<IProductRepository>().FakedObject;
        sut = new ProductService(productRepo);
        var id = 1;
        var expectation = new Product { Id = id };


        // This is different from your example. 
        // The idea is to configure `productRepo`, not `sut`.
        // Also, I don't know the interface for `IProductRepository`,
        // so you'll have to adjust this call to match `GetAll`
        A.CallTo(() => productRepo.GetAll(id)).Returns(new [] {expectation});

        // Act
        var result = await sut.GetProductById(id);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(id, result.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Unfortunately, I cannot adapt your answer to my code (but I suppose it is because of my ignorance). Indeed, my repository does not implement a `GetProductById` method. It only implements a `GetAllProducts` method, which is used by the ` IProductService` to find the product by its `id`. I have added this info in my new edited question.

Comment: I hadn't said that the repository implements `GetProductById`. I said to configure `productRepo.GetAll`. If you configure `GetAll()`, my approach should work, with the caveat that you need to have it return a class that implements `IDbAsyncQueryProvider`, which can be tricky to implement. I am not an EntityFramework user, so suggest following Ben Hall's [Using FakeItEasy with Entity Framework 6](https://benhall.io/using-fakeiteasy-with-entity-framework-6/).
Since you're new to FIE, though, it might be helpful to first practice testing a variation of your code that doesn't use EF.

Comment: thanks again for your help. I will follow your suggestions and I am sure I will get it sorted out.